# OCS sql query to retrieve IM messages for particular users

Tags: sql, message, instant, ocs

I want to output all of the IM messages from an OCS database (LcsLogs), for various different users. I want all of the message they send or receive. I have something like the following at the moment:

```
SELECT * from dbo.Messages where
Messages.FromId = '111' or Messages.ToId = '111' or
Messages.FromId = '222' or Messages.ToId = '222' or
Messages.FromId = '333' or Messages.ToId = '333'
```

I also want to make absolutley sure I am searching *all* of the correct tables etc, and being new to LcsLogs databases, I am still not sure if my basic query is comprehensiev enough. I have seen the following query online:

```
 SELECT * from dbo.Messages, dbo.Users where
 dbo.Users.UserId = Messages.FromId
```

But I got quite a lot of duplication of messages using this query, and was unsure why we were querying "dbo.Users". Any help with this would be much appreciated.

Kind regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this query to get the info that you want:

```
SELECT * from dbo.Messages where
  Messages.FromId in ('111', '222', '333')
  or
  Messages.ToId in ('111', '222', '333')
```

or to remove duplicates on your other query, use distinct like this:

```
SELECT distinct  * from dbo.Messages, dbo.Users where
 dbo.Users.UserId = Messages.FromId
```

Comment: Thanks, the first query is more relevent i think. Is there any other tables i need to think about? And i also notice alot of the messages contain CSS style parameters, is there any way to remove this effeciently? thanks

Comment: Put the result that you have now and the result that you intend and I'll answer it better :)